# Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'signingConfig()'

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to setup gradle to create a Google Play store release in Android Studio 0.4.5.  In gradle settings, I am using the default gradle wrapper.  I used the Project Properties dialog to set up the signing config and 'release' build type.  I only have one build module.  Here is the build.gradle file that resulted:

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig playstore
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
            playstore {
            keyAlias 'mykeyalias'
            storeFile file('playstore.jks')
            keyPassword 'xxxxx'
            storePassword 'xxxxx'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

But I am getting the following error when gradle tries to sync:

```
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'signingConfig()'!
            Possible causes could be:  
            - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
            - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
            - or there is a mistake in a build script
```

Is there something I need to do to setup the correct gradle?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you are using too old an Android plugin version? Can you show the `buildscript` block that brings in the Android plugin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First define your `SigningConfigs` before your `buildTypes` block . Also `playstore` method is inside `signingConfigs` so you have to give a reference in a manner like `signingConfigs.playstore` .

Your final `build.gradle` file should look like this :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"
    }

   signingConfigs {
            playstore {
              keyAlias 'mykeyalias'
              storeFile file('playstore.jks')
              keyPassword 'xxxxx'
              storePassword 'xxxxx'
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.playstore
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked like a charm.  I find it frustrating that I used the Android Studio Project Properties dialog to set up the signingConfigs and it put the signingConfigs *after* the buildTypes in the build.gradle file.  I should probably file that with Google as a bug.

Comment: is it ? Sure file a bug so team will get to know about this and would be able to resolve it in next releases.