# Admob android studio, crashing app

Tags: android, admob

I have put the admob .jar file in my project via project structure:

[image]

And I added code in for the admob banner into my layout files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="taken out for stack"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/yourTasteStatistics"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="@null"

        >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

But when I open a fragment with an ad on it, my app automatically crashes...Any ideas what step I must be missing here?

Here is the output:

```
05-13 17:56:44.053  12606-12606/com.beerportfolio.freeBP E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.beerportfolio.freeBP, PID: 12606
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.beerportfolio.freeBP.BeerPage.onCreateView(BeerPage.java:30)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.beerportfolio.freeBP-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.beerportfolio.freeBP-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.beerportfolio.freeBP.BeerPage.onCreateView(BeerPage.java:30)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 30 is just where the fragments view is inflated. Make sense its crashing there if it does not like my admob ads.

Update:

As noted in the comments I was using out of date libs. I then followed this link for instructions on how to update to use google play services instead.

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?hl=pt-br

My problem is here on this step:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
}
```

When I add that to my grade the gradle fails to sync. My grade looks like this now:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And give me this error:

```
Error:(9, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!

Possible causes could be:  
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (<a href="open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)
  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)
  - or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)
```

Comment: The console shows an error?

Comment: Not showing me an error, I will try again and make sure debug mode is true. Hang on.

Comment: Version 6.4.1 is deprecated.

Comment: Where can I get the new one?

Comment: Get https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Thanks that helps but still getting problems. About to update my above post.

Comment: Question now updated.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976348/build-script-error-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-signingconfig

Comment: Fixed it, I placed it in the wrong gradle file.... NOw i kind of have it working. Its not crashing but the ad is not loading...

SHould I continue with this question here or close this one and start a new one?

Comment: Edit "entire" question, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies block is in the wrong place. It looks like you edited build.gradle in your top level directory.

Open the one in your application module instead. There should be an android block there etc. Or just use the project structure dialog in android studio to edit it.